# list of parent nodes with a list of child referring nodes

Tags: 6, views

I would like to make a list of all parent nodes and under each parent display a list of child nodes that are referencing parent node. Something like drupal.org modules page, except in my case this is not with taxonomy. Using drupal 6 views 2

```
example

parent1
-child1
-child2
-child3
more parent1

parent2
-child1a
-child2a
-child3a
more parent2
```

I am not able to display it using one view. Can anybody help me with some ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you're using Node reference, right? If this is your case the solution is quite simple.

1) Create a view with a contextual argument for displaying all the children of a specified parent.

2) Use Display Suite module to attach this view on a custom display mode of parent nodes. With display suite you can pass the current nid to the view argument. You can also use Views Attach module ( https://drupal.org/project/views_attach )

3) create a view with the list of every parent and set to show the customized display created before.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Another solution is to use modules like Viewfield or Views Field View to attach the first view (child nodes) to the second one (parents). Anyway the basic idea is the same.

Comment: Hi, I need to display such list on one page. Not based on parent argument. All parent nodes with child nodes listed. Or I am not understanding your answer? Hm, the views field view seem like an idea worth exploring. I try that and come back

Comment: The main view (the one created on third step) is a single page with all your parent and child nodes as you asked. The argument are used on the "embedded" views to display child nodes after each parent node.

Comment: Great idea with views field view. Works as you said. Thank you